# Maven plugin "failed to generate resource files" error marker in eclipse (kelper) with propery lifecycle mapping configured

Tags: m2e

I know I don't have a m2e connector but I did configure the lifecycle mapping properly in the pom. In fact, it was working fine. But now, it keeps giving me the above error marker which indicates the goal was mapped properly but the invocation of the goal failed within eclipse. Manually executing the goal from the command line works fine (the resources generated properly). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an eclipse issue. This happened whenever I updated the plugin and installed it locally. I had to restart eclipse and clean the project to make the above error go away.